# How do i prevent an orientation change of a background activty?

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, android-orientation, orientation-changes

I'm preventing an activty from changing to landscape mode via

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

everything works fine except if i call a new activity. When the new activity turns to landscape mode the background activity changes too. How do i prevent this?

Comment: Add this android:screenOrientation="portrait" your <activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Unfortunately i need to archive it dynamically.

Comment: @bapho dynamically means?

Comment: are you using `setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` before you `setContentView` ?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal I do.

Comment: try to put `setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` in `onResume()`

Answer (score 0):

Fix your activity to portrait mode when in onPause.

```
onPause(){
  // Your code to make this app fixed to portrait when in background
}
```

Comment: if i call the new activity and close it very quickly, the onConfigurationChanged() method of the background activity is called. (i use android:configChanges)